# Would a device physically closer to me transfer a file quicker(P2P)

Tags: networking

Hello all I am new to networking and a question arose in my head. Would a device that is physically closer to another device transfer a file quicker than a device which is across the globe if a P2P connection were used?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question probably belongs on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) more than Stack Overflow.

Comment: My guess would be that your speed is only as good as the weakest link. If you have 1 gigabit cable between two computers and you're able to saturate this cable (aka getting 1 gigabit transfer speed), if you add a switch in between you're now depending on this switch also being able to transfer packets at 1 gigabit speed. What *would* go down based on the distance the data has to be transferred is *latency*, the time from when one end sends a request for data, but I'm not sure the speed would, but then, that's why we have different sites for these things.

Comment: Yes, a shorter link is traversed faster than a longer link, since the signal does travel at a finite speed.  But this difference is very likely trivial--the biggest delays are the router and host buffers.

Answer (score 1):

No, not generally.

The maximum throughput between any two nodes is limited by the slowest interconnect they are using in their path. When acknowledgments are used (eg. with TCP), throughput is also limited by congestion, possible send/acknowledgment window size, round-trip time (RTT) - you cannot transfer more than one full window in each RTT period - and packet loss.

Distance doesn't matter basically. However, for long distance a large number of interconnects is likely used, increasing the chance for a weak link, congestion, or packet loss. Also, RTT inevitably increases, requiring a large send window (TCP window scale option).

Whether the links are wired, copper, fiber, or wireless doesn't matter - the latter means there's some risk for additional packet loss, however. P2P or classic client-server doesn't matter either.